# @Input value in TU Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I test an Angular component, which has two @Input values: Object and boolean. Before each test, I initialize this inputs. Only the object is defined but the boolean input field, it is always undefined.

```
// Component declaration
@Component({})
class ComponentA{
@Input()
verif:boolean;
@Input()
ob:A; // any class A
}

// Jasmine Test
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 declarations: [ComponentA]}).compileComponents();
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentA);
 fixture.componentInstance.verif = true; // Not computed, always undefined
 fixutre.componentInstance.ob = new A(); // Computed, defined object
});
```

Comment: can you explain a little more in detail?

Comment: Please supply the component you're testing and the spec file.

Comment: done, see question plz

Comment: hm yeah... you create an entirely different component. you're testing ComponentA but create a MedicalDbComponent. it would help if you'd take the time to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @MarkusDresch it was typo. Fixed